# Dropdown populated througn javascript is showing each character as a dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this javascript method to populate dropdown-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openPopup()
    {
        $("#wrapper").html('');
        $.get('getClanLeads', function(data){

         var options = '';
         $.each(data, function(i,data){
            options +='<option value="'+ data +'">' + data + '</option>';
        });
         $("#wrapper").append('<select>' + options + '</select>');
         alert(data);
         location.href = "#divModalDialog1";
        });
    }

</script>
```

But this is showing the data's characters as the options of the dropdown. Not the data values fetched from the database.
The data is returned from server as-- 
[{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}]
But it is added to dropdown as '[', '{', '"', 'u', 's', 'e', 'r', ...

Comment: example of what data is?

Comment: looks like the data is coming back as a string, that would account to it iterating through it as characters.. you could try `$.each(JSON.parse(data), funct.....` instead.. should work.

Comment: @ Dean Meehan The Data is- [{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}] which I get through server

Answer (score 1):

The data isn't being interpreted as JSON. Changing the outer call to:

```
$.get('getClanLeads', function(data){
  // ...
}, 'json');
```

should help.

After that, you need to be careful about which part of each element you use:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item){
  options +='<option value="'+ item.user_id +'">' + item.user_id + '</option>';
});
```